# Images do not fit container and run outside div

Tags: css

I have a content(div) in which image grid has to be deployed but unfortunately image grid does not fit the container and it runs out of the div. i have uploaded my code on jsfiddle:

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d87aq7yu/1/)

My Html Code:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="content">
<p>Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing the look and formatting of a document written in a markup language. While most often used to change the style of web pages and user interfaces written in HTML and XHTML, the language can be applied to any kind of XML document, including plain XML, SVG and XUL.</p>

<div class="MyBox">
    <ul id="grid">
       <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="http://www.nerdorturd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/css_cascading_style_sheet.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="http://www.nerdorturd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/css_cascading_style_sheet.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="http://www.nerdorturd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/css_cascading_style_sheet.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="http://www.nerdorturd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/css_cascading_style_sheet.jpg"></a></li>  
    </ul>                                    
</div>       
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats wrong in fiddle everything is perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple add

```
 height:auto;
overflow:auto;
```

to `class = MyBox`

[Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d87aq7yu/3/)

Comment: Hy Sanoj it worked. im facing one more problem is caption on images. i want to give caption below the every image inside div. can u load the working fiddle please.

Comment: but you didn't mention in question you would have mentioned before

Comment: @SatishGupta its very simple have a try you just need to add span http://jsfiddle.net/d87aq7yu/6/

Comment: span is not what i was looking for. I had to put caption inside the box.

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/or2ua75e/5/   but its not supporting old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a '`clearfix`' issue.  Add this to your CSS:

```
#content:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Ultimately you can change it to be a class and implement it wherever you have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style too.

```
.MyBox {
display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the updated Fiddle

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d87aq7yu/4/)

Added `overflow:auto;` to `#content`

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    background: #FFF8DC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
}
```